# Making a delegate for a notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, notifications

Lets say i have an integer (hi) that is 0. I want a notification to say 0 in the message. my code is:

```
-(IBAction) alert3;
{
    int hi = 0;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView"
                                            message:@"%d"
                                           delegate:hi
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                  otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

And then i get an error:

"Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'id'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is incomplete. You need to add the message as a string.

Do this:

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView"
                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", hi]
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                  otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

%d is the parameter formatter for an int, that you have to pass after the comma

About the delegate, the delegate is the class that will respond to the messages defined in the UIAlertViewDelegate (for example, when the user touches a button).

If you dont want to control that, just set it to null:

```
delegate:nil
```

Or to self to control it yourself.

Comment: Correct implementation!!